# How to create RxJS subject in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I  am able to create an Observable in my angular component in below mentioned
way

```
...
...
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
..
...
let observable = new Observable( function subscribe(observer) {
        observer.next(1);
        observer.next(2);
        observer.next(3);
        observer.next(4);
        setTimeout(() => {observer.next(5); },9000);
    });
```

But am not aware of how to create a Subject , can some one provide an example 
for the same ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `Rx.Subject` with *Angular* it is no different from using it without *Angular*, the main principle is the same, look at the example below

```js
const subject = new Rx.Subject();
const subscription = subject.subscribe(
  (data) => console.log(data),
  (err) => console.log(err),
  () => console.log('Completed')
);

subject.next(1);
subject.next(2);
subject.next(3);
subject.complete();
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.0.0-beta.7/dist/global/Rx.umd.js"></script>
```

You need to make new instance `Rx.Subject`, then subscribe to it where you need to, and fire event.

Answer (score 14):

Here's a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/jLtFLjWrvHGI0ZPHl10B?p=preview

```
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject'; // from 'rxjs'; for the newer rxjs versions

@Injectable()
export class MyService {

    public invokeEvent:Subject<any> = new Subject();
    
    constructor() {}
}
```

subscribe to it like an observable:

```
  constructor(private _myService: MyService) {
         this._myService.invokeEvent.subscribe((value) => {
           console.log(value); 
         });
       }
```

and push values to it like an observable again with next

```
  ngAfterViewInit(){
      this._myService.invokeEvent.next(1);
  }
```

Comment: I wonder if I really need an entire class just to put `Injectable` on top of `Subject`. Maybe we could shove a bare instance of Subject into the `providers` array?

Comment: @Gherman the thing is you usually put subjects in a shared service so you won't have to create an injectable for all of them. This is just an example.

Comment: It happens that my shared service consists of just one BehaviorSubject and nothing else. Everything that I need is already implemented in BehaviorSubject. So it rather seems like the subject has to be a shared service on its own rather than be put in one. I just have a bunch of components that either change state or view it.

Comment: @Gherman hmm maybe something like `{provide: mySubject, useFactory: ()=> new BehaviourSubject()}` but i think this will again create a class in the background. I will try to test/create a plunker tomorrow.

Comment: Currently we should use: `import {Subject} from 'rxjs'`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by following code

```js
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';


subject = new BehaviorSubject<string>("");


observer = this.subject.asObservable();
     
     
     
     
     //TO FIRE NEXT EVENT
     
this.subject.next("My next value");



    // TO SUBSCRIBE EVENT


this.observer.subscribe({
  next : (value)=>{
    console.log(value); // will return My next value
  }
});
```