# How can I pass data between sibling components in Angular?

Tags: angular, routes, e-commerce

I’m building an ecommerce app with Angular, I wonder how can I pass the total amount from the ShoppingCart component to the Checkout component. 
The two components are sibling.
I saw few ways to do it, like BehaviourSubject and NavigationExtras but I don’t know if they are good practice.

Comment: Maybe this is a good read for you? https://medium.com/@pandukamuditha/angular-5-share-data-between-sibling-components-using-eventemitter-8ebb49b64a0a

Comment: I'm pretty sure this question has been answered many times

Comment: You can create service so it will available everywhere in application. For more data use store concept so you will get value everywhere. Use Angular with Redux
https://github.com/angular-redux/ng-redux

Comment: Your application needs state management such as [ngrx](https://ngrx.io/guide/store) (based on redux). It will take some elbow grease integrating it in to your app but will definitely help you in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

You can use service for shared data. If you have complex use case, that the data is used everywhere and many components can make changes, then manybe you should consider state management process like redux.

Comment: The scenario is this, in my ShoppingCart component i have a button, when this button is clicked the route change, and the Checkout component is loaded instead of ShoppingCart, i would pass the amount variable in the ShoppingCart to the Checkout like a POST variable in PHP, it is possible ?

Comment: If i understand correctly, you want to pass the amount using url? Yes, it is possible, you can add amount parameter in URL and in another component (like Checkout) use ActivatedRoute to get the parameter from URL.

Answer (score 0):

Matteo the best solution for me is used the [Subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40439327/how-to-create-rxjs-subject-in-angular-2). The logic are these:

1. Create the Subject in the father's `ngOnInit()`( create the channel)
2. Pass the Subject to siblings ( sign in the siblings in the channel)
3. In sibling's ngOnInit() you can register the sibling in to the channel
4. when you click on checkout yuou can notify the component that are listening in the channel with the total amout.
5. destroy channel and unregister the component

Comment: Do you mean like that https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/ ? Using the BehaviorSubject ?

Comment: @yes! But I suggest you to not create  DataService ( at the end of page), because you don't need ( I think in your application) to share the service with another components that aren't parent and siglings. I use the DataService code in parent code.

Comment: So, you have injected the parent component into the sibling ? and how can i do the 5th step (of your list) ?

Comment: from the èather you create "messageSource,currentMessage "( like in dataService ) and inject the "messageSource , currentMessage " to siblings. In sibling's ngOnInit you "subscribe" the component. When the user click on checkout you call "nect(1500)". This notify the sibling that there is one change. at the end you can use ngonDestroy to destroy all

Comment: @Matteo is it work? can you give me correct answer?